# Redux and Sagas: can't connect properly

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a project where used Saga and Redux Store, this is the project bootstrapping method:

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { fork } from 'redux-saga/effects';

...

const bootstrap = async () => {
    const configuration = await config.env();
    init(configuration);

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        ...reducers,
    })

    function* rootSaga() {
        yield sagas.map(saga => fork(saga))
    }

    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));

    const App = (): Element<*> => (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <div>
                <WorstProjectInMyLife />
            </div>
        </Provider>
    );

    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
};

bootstrap();
```

And this is where we dispatching state to props:

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectIsFetching = createSelector(
    parentSelector,
    (parentState: StateRecord = new StateRecord()) => parentState.isFetching
);

const mapStateToProps = (state: StateType) => ({
    isFetching: selectIsFetching(state)
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    ...actions
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WorstProjectInMyLife);
```

But the store is always empty, so I'm afraid that this is didn't connected properly. Can you guys please take a look, maybe I missed something? I'm really straggling with this for a few days already and going mental because have no idea why this won't work. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to setup a simple scenario similar to yours and it seems to work. Can you provide some more context & code? The whole state of the app is undefined at first? (remember you are not defining a default state) Is the parent selector working properly?

Comment: I tried to pass an empty object or `Immutable.Map({})` as default state, still didn't work.

Comment: I've edited the answer... can you please provide more context? Maybe you can try to replicate it somehow in https://codesandbox.io or something.